# counting numbers beginning with 1,2, etc python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know how to count the occurrence of a character by using str.count(sub[, start[, end]]), but is there an easy way to count words that begin with a character in a string?

```
b = "this is 100 111 123 test data"
sum(1 for word in b.split() if word.startswith('t'))
2
sum(1 for word in b.split() if word.startswith('1'))
3
```

works, but I think I'm supposed to count without using sum or startswith for this assignment.

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

Given your string as

> > instr="I know how to count the occurrence of a character by using str.count(sub[, start[, end]]), but is there an easy way to count words that begin with a character in a string?"

If you need to count all words which begin with a character in a string say `vowels=set("aeiou")` then you can so something like

```
>>> sum(1 for c in re.findall("(\w)\w*",instr) if c in vowels)
11
```

and incase you want to find all words that begin with a number, then

```
sum(1 for c in re.findall("(\d)\w*",instr) if c in vowels)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
 s = 'this is a test'
 sum(1 for word in s.split() if word.startswith('t'))
```

Comment: @malenkiy_scot: Can you please amplify as to why this doesn't work?

Comment: @Abhijit: I'm assuming you know why it does not work. For the benefit of others: run `"I say: 'This does not work' ".split()`, the third word will be `'This`, so if you try to count words starting with a `T` you'll miss it. Note that it's a perfectly legitimate string.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot: I see your point, but it may work for my simple program!

Comment: I think it is important to do things the right way to begin with: simple programs tend to become complex with time. In any case, I was just pointing out that there is more here than meets the eye. By the way, @Abhijit 's solution covers my case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question (an example would have been helpful) you could try something like this:

```
 s = 'this is a test'
 target = 't'
 sum([i[0].count(target) for i in s.split()])
```

will tell you that 2 words in the string started with your target letter ('t')

```
 sum([1 for i in s.split() if i[0] == target])
```

is an equivalent, but neater, solution (but suffers from the same problem as pointed out in the comment)

Comment: Ah .. I see what you mean .. thanks. An example (like yours) would have been helpful.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to get each start letter. You can use a list comprehension on your text for this:

```
In [40]: tgt="This is an example text. There are several words starting with letters."

In [41]: fl=[word[0] for word in tgt.split()]

In [42]: fl
Out[42]: ['T', 'i', 'a', 'e', 't', 'T', 'a', 's', 'w', 's', 'w', 'l']
```

Now count them.

For individual letters, just use the count method on the generated list:

```
In [43]: fl.count('T')
Out[43]: 2
```

For all the letters, just use a set and dictionary:

```
In [50]: d={}

In [51]: for l in set(fl):
            d[l]=fl.count(l) 

In [52]: d
Out[52]: {'T': 2, 'a': 2, 'e': 1, 'i': 1, 'l': 1, 's': 2, 't': 1, 'w': 2}
```